# How to upload 1 image + convert to base64 + display the same image with the same ID multiple times on the same HTML page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, upload, base64

It works well but only display the image one time... Thank you for your help

```html
<input type="file" id="file-upload" class="upload-file bg-highlight shadow-s rounded-s " accept="image/*">

<img id="image-data" src="images/empty.png" class="img-fluid">

<img id="image-data" src="images/empty.png" class="img-fluid">

<img id="image-data" src="images/empty.png" class="img-fluid">

<img id="image-data" src="images/empty.png" class="img-fluid">
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work as expected. Choose an image file and use `FileReader` to read image data.

```js
document.getElementById('file-upload').addEventListener('change', e => {
const file = e.target.files[0];
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('#image-data').forEach(i => i.src = reader.result);
});
if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
});
```

```css
#image-data { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-upload" class="upload-file bg-highlight shadow-s rounded-s " accept="image/*">

<img id="image-data" src="images/empty.png" class="img-fluid">

<img id="image-data" src="images/empty.png" class="img-fluid">

<img id="image-data" src="images/empty.png" class="img-fluid">

<img id="image-data" src="images/empty.png" class="img-fluid">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I try now and let you know if it works :)

Comment: Well done!!! it works very well and as expected!!!! you save my day!!! +1 . I tried to give you a vote but there is this message : Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.